# How to automatically include js/css file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In normal web project, we have to inlcude js/css file like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/main.js"></script>
```

whenever we add a new css file or js file we have to add one more line.

In Meteorjs, its automatically taken care by Meteor itself, but for non-meteor project, can we do that?

for example, I just put any js file into js folder and I don't need to care about it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "browserify"

in the "package.json"

```
..."scripts": {
"build": "browserify public/javascripts/main.js > public/javascripts/main-build.js",....
```

in the "main.js"

```
var ObjectName = require('./another_file');
```

html

```
<script src="javascripts/main-build.js"></script>
```

another_file.js

```
ObjectName = function(){ ..... }
module.exports = ObjectName;
```